# Add font awesome for toast ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

### Add Font awesome to toast

I can't find a way to add font awesome to toast message on ionic 4 because ionic 4 is shadow Dom for all web controller

Comment: include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

you can follow the next code to add custom font to toasts.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ToastController } from "@ionic/angular";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "home.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["home.page.scss"]
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(private toastController: ToastController) {}

  async showToast() {
    let toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: "Your settings have been saved.",
      duration: 2000
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  async showCustomToast() {
    let toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: "Your settings have been saved.",
      duration: 2000,
      cssClass: "CustomToast"
    });
    toast.present();
  }
}
```

On documentation of [Toast component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast) there are a property to define your custom css styles.

[image: Toast property]

This class need to be on src/global.css

```
.CustomToast {
   font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

[image: Custom toast]

Generally when you need to custom a component (alerts, loaders, etc.), you need follow this process.

I hope I've helped :)

Comment: thanks for your replay but i want to add font awesome  Not Font css style https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery

Comment: @AhmedMohamed it was an example, load the font on your project and use the font on the css file.

Answer (score -1):

put the html for your fontawesome in the message parameter.

```
async showCustomToast() {
    let toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: "<i class="fas-fa-edit"></i> Your settings have been saved.",
      duration: 2000,
      cssClass: "CustomToast"
    });
    toast.present();
  }
```